# DataGridView Select Row with Specific Cell value [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am using this code to move the row selection programmatically

```
            For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows()
                If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString().Equals(code) Then
                    row.Selected = True
                End If
                Exit For
            Next
```

But the Problem I am facing is This only Changes the highlighted row but doesn't actually select the row..
When I try to get data from selected row it gives data from previous row not the blue highlighted row.
Actually Row header Tick type thing doesn't move It stays on previous row.

Comment: You also have to set the selected column to move the cursor position `DataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells(0)` right before `row.Selected = True`

Comment: This is working for row index = 0
However if row index is greater than 1 then its not going there

Comment: @AlexB. Can you please write me some code that works.......
Because this code only works for zero index and not greater than zero.....
Please help me

Comment: Ah look at your code again closely... `Exit For` is at the wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to set the selceted cell:

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows()
       If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString().Equals(code) Then
          row.Selected = True
          DataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells(0)
          Exit For
      End If
 Next
```

The reason your code works only for the first row is that `Exit For` was outside the `If` statement. If you include it the code works like a charm.